# many-to-many where clause

Tags: java, hibernate

Given 3 tables:

```
student (id)
student_to_class (student_id, class_id)
class (id)
```

I'd like to apply a where clause on the student_to_class where student_id = :studentId. I've found many examples that apply where clause on "class" table or "student" table, but not the many-to-many table.

The student table has a @ManyToMany

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
    name = "student_to_class",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", nullable = false) },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "class_id", nullable = false) }
)
private Set<ClassEntity> classes;
```

The class table has a @ManyToMany

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
    name = "student_to_class",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "class_id", nullable = false) },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", nullable = false) }
)
private Set<StudentEntity> students;
```

Here is the query I'm trying to translate into Criteria:

```
select * from student, student_to_class where student_to_class.student_id = 1 and student.id = student_to_class.class_id
```

I'm trying to figure out how to reference the many-to-many table since I don't have an actual class representing this table.

```
Criteria c = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ClassEntity.class);
c.createAlias("student_to_class", "entities"); // how to reference the student_to_class ?
c.add(Restrictions.eq("entities.user_id", studentEntity.getId()));
```

But I get an error, which makes sense to me, but I haven't had much luck fixing it:
    could not resolve property: student_to_class

Answer (score 1):

Since the `studentid` in the Student table will be the same as the `studentid` in the `student_to_class` table there is no need to filter by the join table.  Simply run the where clause against `student.student_id`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Can you please explain with code?